# blender crashes my entire pc

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Operating system:Windows 10
Graphics card: 980TI

Ive tested in: 2.82a 2.83

Every time i use cycles either for full renders or just the viewport after several frames it crashes, it doesnt matter if i use gpu or cpu they both crash the whole pc to a reboot my friend was able to render my file just fine and i cant seem to render anything more complicated then the start up screen in cycles
its my first day using blender and im not real sure what to do

Comment: You should check your CPU and GPU temperatures when rendering (and crashing) with something like HWMonitor.

Comment: I did that and my CPU gets up to 106c and shuts down so I'm assuming that's the issue my question is what's the solution and why is it so hot in the first place

Comment: 106°C ? That's way too hot! It could be some cooling system issue, imho.

Comment: @m.ardito my ryzen also has a 10° offset so it's not actually 106 it's 96 which is also the max temp for the cpu before it shuts down what I think the problem is, is the hot room and the computer being set to high performance and able to max out the cpu tomorrow I'm going to lower the power draw and cap the cpu at like 80% to see if it fixed it then I'll move from there

Answer (score 1):

Your CPU is too hot!

Why ?
When you ask blender to render, the CPU (and/or GPU) is used at it's maximum (100% usage at max frequency). This produces heat.

What can you do?
Check the air flow.
**Global case airflow**
[image: case air flow]
The air has to be able to come in and out (clean the grids and case fans for dust) and through (move cables and anything that is in the path).

**CPU Air Flow**
[image: CPU Air flow]
Make sure the fan is turning and clean the dust in the fan and heat sink.

You can buy a bigger/better CPU fan/heat sink.
You can use watercooling if it's not enough. (technical and expensive but powerful)